# Filtrar array (multidimensional) javascript

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando filtrar un array a partir de un sub array con un multi filtro.

Necesito filtrar por ejemplo, dentro de "features" => "properties" por id o por el valor que mande.

Tengo una prueba en https://jsfiddle.net/chabri88/42v7bj8a/96/

A ver si me explico mejor con el código.

Gracias a todos de ante mano

Mis datos:

```
const data = [{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": 
    [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "ID": "1",
          "League": "NL",
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-112.066667, 33.445278]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "ID": "2",
          "League": "RS",
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-112.066667, 33.445278]
        }
      }
    ]
}]
```

Lo que necesito que retorne si por ejemplo el ID es 1:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": 
    [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "ID": "1",
          "League": "NL",
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-112.066667, 33.445278]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Filtros:

```
let filters = {
  League: ["RS Sox"],
  ID: ["2", "4"]
};
```

My función:

```
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  // no sub array return
    return array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
}
```

Aquí se aplica el multi filtro

```
var filtered = multiFilter(data, filters);
```

Respuesta corregida por @OscarGarcia para quien le interese:
https://jsfiddle.net/chabri88/42v7bj8a/107/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código:

- Tu variable `data` es una matriz de un único elemento.
- Los datos que quieres filtrar no están directamente en cada elemento, si no bajo `elemento.features`.

De modo que, corrigiendo estos dos problemas, un ejemplo funcional de tu código quedaría así:

```js
const data = [{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "1",
        "League": "NL",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -112.066667, 33.445278 ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "2",
        "League": "RS",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -112.066667, 33.445278 ]
      }
    }
  ]
}];
        
let filters = {
  League: [ "RS Sox" ],
  ID: [ "2", "4" ]
};

function multiFilterOr(array, filters) {
  /* Filtramos cada uno de los elementos de la propiedad "features" */
  return array.features.filter(elemento => {
    /* Comprobamos cada una de las condiciones */
    for (const filtro in filters) {
      /* Si está entre los esperados la mantenemos */
      if (filters[filtro].indexOf(elemento.properties[filtro]) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    /* Ningún filtro se cumple, lo borramos */
    return false;
  });
}

function multiFilterAnd(array, filters) {
  /* Filtramos cada uno de los elementos de la propiedad "features" */
  return array.features.filter(elemento => {
    /* Comprobamos cada una de las condiciones */
    for (const filtro in filters) {
      /* En cuanto una no está entre los esperados, la borramos */
      if (filters[filtro].indexOf(elemento.properties[filtro]) === -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    /* Todos los filtros se cumplen, lo mantenemos */
    return true;
  });
}

/* Analizamos el primer elemento de "data" (y único) */
document.getElementById("json1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
  multiFilterOr(data[0], filters), undefined, 2
);
document.getElementById("json2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
  multiFilterAnd(data[0], filters), undefined, 2
);
```

```html
<pre id="json1"></pre>
<pre id="json2"></pre>
```

Comment: Wow... Iba bastante desencaminado, el caso que sin sub array hasta ahí fácil, y después me he ido complicado. Excelente tu respuesta y muchísimas gracias crack!